# How to read and save content of a local file?

Tags: html, angular

I have to read a file browsed from local and save the content in array in order to display a part of it in the page. I am able to read the content . But it doesnt let me save to local variable. How can we do that ?

```
  readFile(file: any) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        console.log(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file.target.files[0]);
}
```

```
 <input class="fieldPad"  id="input-file-id" multiple type="file" (change)="readFile($event)" />
```

Want to save the content of **reader.result** in an array.But it's read only data. How to save this? Please help.

Comment: Which type of file are you trying to save? And show us how you are trying to save data and the matching error (if existing).

Comment: browsing a .txt file from local. by save I mean store the content of the file in a string array

Comment: a .txt file content is just a string, if you want to save it into a string array, you just  need to push the content into the array : array.push(content)